# How are subsea HVDC cables laid without cutting internet cables

Tags: infrastructure

Apparently subsea HVDC cables are actually buried around 2m below the sea bed using some kind of plough-like device. How can that be done without cutting internet cables?

Comment: Source for that? I suspect that most cables are buried only in the shallows (< 30 m?) on the approach to shore.

Comment: if you could do that 2000 m below the surface across all terrain, avoiding other cables would be child's play.

Comment: Check out the pipe burying equpment used by farmers - same principle.

Comment: See [Introduction to HVDC Subsea Cables](https://europacable.eu/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Introduction-to-HVDC-Subsea-Cables-16-July-2012_.pdf). It says a cable from San Francisco to Pittsburg was buried for its entire length to a depth of 6ft.

Comment: How much HVDC is transmitted any significant distance at depth ?

Comment: I was familiar with oil/gas platform applications and had made the wrong  assumption that the cables were AC.

Comment: San Francisco to Pittsburg .... yeah definitely sub**sea** all the way.

Comment: That was just an example. See [this document](https://europacable.eu/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Introduction-to-HVDC-Subsea-Cables-16-July-2012_.pdf) for more details. However it does give an actual answer (see my answer).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - It's actually Pittsburg, California.  The route is entirely underwater, but entirely within San Fransisco Bay and its associated waters - certainly not very deep.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with all the Pittsburghs of America. Did he think it was on land?  I assumed he was just complaining that it wasn't out in the ocean.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like they are not buried in deep water so I guess the carefully arrange crossings to only occur there.

From [this document](https://europacable.eu/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Introduction-to-HVDC-Subsea-Cables-16-July-2012_.pdf), page 41:

> The cables are buried in the seabed sediment up to depths of 400-600 m, below this depth they are simply laid down on the bottom of the sea. In places with strong sea currents or steep slopes they are fastened to the seabed.